# Confused by examples of giving elements of quotient rings without repeats

Tags: abstract-algebra

So I have two examples from class that are causing me some confusion. We’re using the following fact (stated as Corollary 3.20(b) in our notes): $[a]_{I}=[b]_{I}$ iff $a-b\in I$ iff $a=b+x$ for some $x\in I.$

Example 1:

[image]

Example 2:
Let $R=\mathbb{R}[X]$ and $I=\langle X^2+1\rangle$. Then for $a,b,c,d\in \mathbb{R}$ we have $$[a+bX]_{I}=[C+dX]_{I}$$ iff $a+bX = c+dX + (X^2+1)g(X)$ for some $g(X)\in R$. So $a=c$ and $b=d$ and thus $$R/I=\{[a+bX]_{I}:a,b\in \mathbb{R}\}$$ gives all the elements of $R/I$ without repeats.

So what I don’t understand is why neither of these two examples follows a similar format or the fact (Corollary 3.20(b)) stated above. For the first example I would expect $[a+bi]_{I}=[c+di]_{I}$ iff $(a+bi)-(c+di)\in I$ iff $a+bi = (c+di) + x$ for some $x \in I$ (with “$a=a+bi$” and “$b=c+di$”). For the second I'd have thought it'd be $a+bX=c+dX+g(X)$ for some $g(X)\in I.$

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: The first does use that Lemma but they omitted the details of its application. Write out the details. The 2nd explicitly uses it. Note $\,h\in I = (X^2+1)\Bbb R[X]\iff h = (x^2+1)g\, $ for some $\,g\ \in \Bbb R[X].\ \ $

Comment: @BillDubuque Ah, that makes sense! So for the first one the missing step is $(a+bi)=(c+di)+nx+nyi$ for some $x,y\in\mathbb{Z}$, I believe. Is the first proof not overly wordy, by the way? I'm struggling to get my head around the latter parts. Could we go straight from $a\equiv c\pmod{n}$ and $b\equiv d\pmod{n}$ to $a=c, b=d$ for $a,b,c,d=\{0,1,\dots,n-1\}$? Many thanks.